Batman Package Installation Problem
I am working on a virtual environment named tran and trying to install the batman-package for exoplanet transit data fitting. But it's giving me this error. What's the problem here? [Note: I am using windows 11]
 Collecting batman-package
  Downloading batman-package-2.4.9.tar.gz (394 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 394.8/394.8 KB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-2.2.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (12.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.9/12.9 MB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: batman-package
  Building wheel for batman-package (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for batman-package (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5_m9s78j\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'extras_requires'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      Checking for OpenMP support...
      Did not detect OpenMP support.
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for batman-package
Failed to build batman-package
ERROR: Could not build wheels for batman-package, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 24.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\Projects\TransitFinder\tran\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


Isn't this question meant to be one dealing with Coding in Python? We do have a separate Stack Exchange for it. You better post it there.

The batman package is developed by and for astronomers. So I thought this was a good place to ask. I think I'll post this in that Stack Exchange too if I don't get any answer here.

Read the error message: "Did not detect OpenMP support. error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"

Apparently the Build Tools were much more complicated to deal with. I solved the problem by using the Windows Subsystem for Linux and run the code using a virtual environment. This may be a better solution.

@sheyahi Coding related to astronomy is generally considered on topic here
